# Getting the right converter for this 110/120v device, where the power is 220/240v

Tags: voltage, transformer

I have an appliance designed for 110/120v. It says it runs peak at 1200 watts, but I can't find yet any mention of Amps. I'll be using it in Europe at 220/240v, if it is possible.

I understand I can get a converter, but from what I've read it isn't just as simple as getting a 220/240 => 110/120 volt transformer. Or is it?

How do you calculate this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but consumer electronics are off topic here per the [faq].

Comment: Fair enough, but this is more a question about converting volts.

Comment: After your edit, it isn't anymore indeed. We'd like to see some reference on "what I've read" though. Could you add a source?

Comment: What you need is called an autotransformer that it rated for the load that you want to use it for (watts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amps * Voltage = Watts. So 10 A * 120 V = 1200 W. Alternately 5 A * 240 V = 1200 W. So you need a transformer or converter rated for 5 A on the 240 V side and 10 A on the 120 V side.

Comment: That is what I was wondering! Thank you heaps Brian.